# Clear cell contents based on color?

Tags: excel

Is it possible to clear a large number of cells contents based on color alone?  I don't think that simply filtering is going to work well on this because the dataset is large and 'wide'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will clear the content of any cell within the range A1:G8 filled with yellow (65535). Change the color for your color and the range for your range. This is kind of crude, sorry.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Range("A1:G8").Select
    For Each Cell In Selection
        If Cell.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbYellow Then
            Cell.Clear
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: where can you find the decimal representation of colors at?

Comment: You can use [RGB](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm), will probably be easier. I changed the macro. Also you can always record a macro and highlight a cell a color to find out its color code

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need this done programatically, it can be faster to just use Find and Replace (Ctrl-H).

1. Press `Ctrl-H`
2. Click `Options > >`
3. Click the top  `Format...` button to search for for colored cells (use the `Fill` tab)
4. Leave the `Replace with` field blank to delete the contents of cells with the format you specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear cells by background color using Excel's filter options.

---

#### For Excel 2013 & 2010

1. Open a worksheet where each column has a header row.

   <kbd>[image: Worksheet with header row]</kbd>
2. Enable column filtering with **Data -> Sort & Filter -> Filter**

   <kbd>[image: Clicking the filter command]</kbd>
3. Click the **drop-down-arrow** on a column, go to **Filter by Color**, and select a color you want to view. (*Any non-colored cells will be hidden*)

   <kbd>[image: Filtering a column]</kbd>
4. Select the remaining cells, **right-click** and select **Clear Contents**.

   <kbd>[image: Selecting clear contents]</kbd>
5. To unhide the remaining cells, disable column filtering with **Data -> Sort & Filter -> Filter**

   <kbd>[image: Final results without colored cells]</kbd>